# JavaScript get redirect target without loading target URL

Tags: javascript, redirect, fetch

Would it be possible to get the location of a redirect without actually visiting the page? I'm making a userscript and I want to use a redirect to get some query parameters but not load the destination page as it is expensive for the server to load. I've tried to use "redirect": "manual", but it only gives me an opaque redirect (which does not have the destination URL anywhere). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the destination URL due to security reasons. According to the [whatwg fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#atomic-http-redirect-handling), redirects are opaque in order to prevent cross-site scripting attacks as HttpOnly cookies may be sent and allow for privilege escalation.